# WAMP & WordPress - Having issues after installing plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp

I am using WAMP (Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.4.3) & WordPress 3.4.2.

Everything was fine until I started to add and activate plugins now I get different sort of errors on the front-end/Admin e.g.

> "Notice: Undefined index: plugin_version in
>   C:\repo\wpdev\wp-content\plugins\wp-rss-multi-importer\inc\upgrade.php
>   on line 11"

And

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'feedslug' in
>   C:\repo\wpdev\wp-content\plugins\wp-rss-multi-importer\inc\rss_feed.php
>   on line 21."

IF I deactivate the plugins everything seems to be fine. I have installed WAMP & WP 2X. The plugins work fine on MediaTemple. The error messages vary depending on the plugins. Search Google and came up empty.

Answer (score 0):

These are Notices and Warnings, which optionally show up depending on your PHP error reporting settings.  Find your php.ini and set the following:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Note, you can find your php.ini location using the `phpinfo();` function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the author of the plugin you are using, while waiting for an update you can get rid of that error by commenting out these lines in inc/rss_feed.php, e.g.

```
//if (!empty($feed_options)){

//add_feed($feed_options['feedslug'], 'rssmi_feed');

//}
```